# Android api29 How to automatically add app icon on the home screen at install?

Tags: java, android

I would like my app to automatically add the launch icon on the home screen at installation.

What I've tried already:

addShortcut method in ActivityMain

```
private void addShortcut() {

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));

    addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I think this method is a bit out of date?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run code in direct response to your own app being installed the first time - only once the user opens your app.  However, if the user installs your app from Google Play, it will generally add the icon to the home screen by default.